# Can I pass a querystring that translates to a List<int> on the server?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-maps, jquery

I'm writing a Google Maps app that requests data from the server using jQuery's $.ajax() to send the request to my ASP.Net MVC Contoller. This control expects a List for the amenity types. What should the querystring look like for this?

I've tried

http://localhost:9090/mapamenities?amenityTypes=1,5

http://localhost:9090/mapamenities?amenityTypes=[1,5]

with no luck.

The SearchRquest attribute I'm trying to bind to is

```
public List<int> AmenityTypes { get; set; }
```

Thanks
Denis

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try `?amenityTypes=1&amenityTypes=5`.

Answer (score 3):

The default MVC model binder will handle primitive collections as per earl's answer. If you have any need to bind complex types take a look at [this project.](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx)

Comment: fixed the link to Phil Haack's blog :)

Comment: That's true for the general case. It should work for primitive types (such as `int`), though, as is also mentioned in the blog post you point to.

Comment: Nice one, thanks. Was trying to answer from my phone but can't work out how to copy URLs on it! Will stick to laptop in future.

Comment: @earl. Good point, I hadn't realised the default model binder did that, the blog confirms it does as well. +1.

Comment: Yep, ?amenityTypes=1&amenityTypes=5 for this case. Thaks for the link though.